# Use SELECT results to make a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to execute the following SELECT statements:

```
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE A=1 and date between 2013-02 and 2013-03
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE A=1 and date between 2013-03 and 2013-04
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE A=1 and date between 2013-04 and 2013-05
....
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE B=1 and date between 2013-02 and 2013-03
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE B=1 and date between 2013-03 and 2013-04
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE B=1 and date between 2013-04 and 2013-05
...etc
```

What's the fastest query and can I have the results arranged in a table like:

```
date    |A=1  |B=1  |C=1  |...
2013-Feb|count|count|count|
2013-Mar|count|...
```

Comment: Extract the month from date and do a GROUP BY with month. Finally count.

Comment: This is a pivot table, for an example of solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'),
       SUM(CASE WHEN A=1 THEN 1 END) AS Acount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN B=1 THEN 1 END) AS Bcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN C=1 THEN 1 END) AS Ccount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN D=1 THEN 1 END) AS Dcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E=1 THEN 1 END) AS Ecount
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```

If the only values in columns `A` through `E` are 0 or 1 (or possibly `NULL`), then we can simplify to:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'),
       SUM(A) AS Acount,
       SUM(B) AS Bcount,
       SUM(C) AS Ccount,
       SUM(D) AS Dcount,
       SUM(E) AS Ecount
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can have **GROUP BY** function

```
    SELECT 
    to_char(date,'YYYY-MM') as date,
    CASE WHEN A=1 THEN COUNT(A)  END as A ,
    CASE WHEN B=1 THEN COUNT(B)  END as B ,
    CASE WHEN C=1 THEN COUNT(C)  END as C ,
    CASE WHEN D=1 THEN COUNT(D)  END as D ,
    CASE WHEN E=1 THEN COUNT(E)  END as E  
    from table_name group by date order by date
```

This query groups the column based on year and month and provides you the result